# I used this code below to simple display multiple images from links but application closed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments, android-gridview

I have worked like this on my image displaying from web and My code is :

LetsTry.java

```
public class LetsTry extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;

    String[] imageLocation = { "http://sandipjagdale.com/images/logo.png",
            "http://sandipjagdale.com/images/logo.png",
            "http://sandipjagdale.com/images/logo.png" };

    public LetsTry(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageLocation.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0 == ((ImageView)arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

        for(int i = 0; i < imageLocation.length; i++)
        {
            iv.setImageResource(imageLocation[i]);
        }

        return iv;

    }
}
```

Main.Java

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        LetsTry adapter = new LetsTry(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Shows Error under `iv.setImageResource`
I followed this code which is in [manishkpr](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/) How could i show this type of image gallery using this web url images.

Comment: what error does it show? Please post logcat output.

Comment: error given at under "iv.setImageResource" ' A RED LINE ' Without resolve am not able to run it.

Comment: What error? You can hover on red line, and read what that is.

Comment: The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String) " Change to ' setImageAlpha ' Change to 'setImageURI ' Change to ' setImageLavel ' "

Comment: That's because you are trying to set String in imageview. Which is not allowed.

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-load-image-from-internet.html). First you need to retrieve image's bitmap and then set it to your imageview.

Comment: I got it, but i want to show Images from link and create gallery view like facebook that means " images shown with it's description which is on server. " how to do that ?

Comment: Because you are loading images from network so you will need to first download image using `Android-Universal-Image-Loader`,`volley` libs then set Bitmap to ImageView

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have downloaded Universal-Image-Loader but after Importing in ADT it's shows many errors like layout not found which already imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ls use this code to set your Url of Image to Image view.

```
  for(int i = 0; i < imageLocation.length; i++)
    {
        iv.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageLocation[i]));
    }



 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ImageView iv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
            new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    iv.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL("http://sandipjagdale.com/images/logo.png"));
}

public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

It is working fine.

```
  public class GalleryView extends Activity {

String[] imageLocation = { "http://sandipjagdale.com/images/logo.png",
        "http://sandipjagdale.com/images/logo.png",
        "http://sandipjagdale.com/images/logo.png" };
LinearLayout imageView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
            new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();      
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    try {
        // InputStream in = (new URL("www.google.com").openStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    Gallery ga = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
    ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));


}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    int imageBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        ctx = c;
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(
                R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        ta.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return imageLocation.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);

        iv.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromURL(imageLocation[arg0]));
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
        iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
        return iv;
    }
}

 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Not Worked Still same showing error at " iv.setImageResource "

Comment: use  iv.setImageBitmap.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(451): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.FixedLengthInputStream
at com.example.secondchance.LetsTry.getBitmapFromURL(LetsTry.java:64)
at com.example.secondchance.LetsTry.instantiateItem(LetsTry.java:50)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)

Comment: Have you given Internet Permission in your Manifest file ??

Comment: Yes, Have you worked on retrieve multiple images from server ?? if you had than say your concept or idea that how you worked on it, i'll try it.

Comment: I working on your Image Links See demo given above. I am Able to download Image from Server.

Comment: Sir, I accept it but for multiple images ?? i used String[] imageLocation means Array

Comment: you Array code is Accurate but may be problem in ViewPager Adapter

Comment: May be... Thank you bro.. If you ever solve this Image Gallery View from server respond me... Felt nice to share it with you..

Comment: @Mr.ls I am attaching Gallery view Class above for your array of images, Just check it and revert me back.

Comment: It's seems good, Images shows in gallery but images not shows in ImageView

Comment: It's work, but You have created ImageView, In tha imageView Images not displayed

Comment: I am just showing images in gallery only. you can show image in imageview on Click event of gallery accorging to index its very easy bro. And also accept and vote up my answer if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Universal Image Loader lib for android. Below is a link explaining how to use it.

http://javatechig.com/android/universal-image-loader-android-library